# how to add menu to section title?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a section with TITLE_BAR, and i try to add a menu to the section header (like in the PDE editors).
All I could find is the context menu.

Comment: There isn't enough information in this question to properly answer.  Please include some code or screenshots as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the tutorial in the previous answer will work for sections - as far as I know the menu contributions (from a plugin.xml) only apply to a view tool bar or menu - not the section header.

You could try investigating `Section.setTextClient(...);`, you can certainly add a tool bar using that, so could use a drop-down button in order to show a menu, if that would achieve what you want?

This article has some interesting form / section related information too, though not directly related to your problem

[Eclipse Forms: New in 3.3](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Forms33/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are creating a view and you want to add a menu to the view.  Here is an article describing the way to do that:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-3.3menu/index.html

Use the Menu Location URI scheme menu: and specify the view Id.